# Group count by month

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to return results for how many customers have 'enrolled' within a month. At the moment it returns a count per specific dates. see below:

[image: Count for customers enrolled per day]

Here is the code in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult About()
        {
            IQueryable<EnrollmentDateGroup> data = from customer in db.Customers
                                                   group customer by customer.EnrollmentDate  into dateGroup

                                                   select new EnrollmentDateGroup()
                                                   {
                                                       EnrollmentDate = dateGroup.Key,
                                                       CustomerCount = dateGroup.Count() 

        };
```

Can anyone advise on how i can have a count for how many customers enrolled per month?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I get the following error when i use:

```
group customer by new { customer.EnrollmentDate.Year, customer.EnrollmentDate.Month } into dateGroup
```

[image]

Comment: `group customer by new { customer.EnrollmentDate.Year, customer.EnrollmentDate.Month }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the month and year, alone. When you pass the full date, it includes a day component that's going to mess up the grouping. For example:

```
group customer by new { Year = customer.EnrollmentDate.Year, Month = customer.EnrollmentDate.Month }
```

**UPDATE**

That's because you're tying to set the key directly to your `EnrollmentDate` propery, and the key is now an anonymous type, not a `DateTime`. Either create a `DateTime` or do something different.

```
EnrollmentDate = new DateTime(m.Key.Year, m.Key.Month, 1),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use casting in your GROUPBY clause

GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4))

Comment: That's only applicable with actual SQL. The OP here is using LINQ to SQL, which is a different beast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var result = from s in data
             group s by new { date = new DateTime(s.EnrollmentDate.Year, s.EnrollmentDate.Month, 1)} into g 
select new {
date = g.Key.date,
Sum = g.Sum(x=>x.CustomerCount)
};
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could group by a new `DateTime`, as it's technically different object instances, but apparently group by can compensate for that. However, at that point, there's no need to wrap it in an anonymous object. Just do `group s by new DateTime(s.EnrollmentDate.Year, s.EnrollmentDate.Month, 1)`